# Falha ao gerar APK

Tags: android, ionic

Então, estou seguindo esse tutorial:

http://www.tiagoporto.com/blog/tutorial-de-configuracao-do-ambiente-ionic-android-no-windows/

Que ensina a configurar o ionic com cordova para gerar apk's android

Fiz tudo corretamente. Mas, no último passo, onde deveria gerar o apk, dá o seguinte erro abaixo e não gera o APK.

```
Na verdade, nem mesmo a pasta android/"build" está gerando,
```

Onde estou errando?

```
D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio>ionic cordova build android
> ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform android
[16:38:21]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.0
[16:38:21]  build dev started ...
[16:38:21]  clean started ...
[16:38:21]  clean finished in 9 ms
[16:38:21]  copy started ...
[16:38:22]  deeplinks started ...
[16:38:22]  deeplinks finished in 46 ms
[16:38:22]  transpile started ...
[16:38:31]  transpile finished in 9.52 s
[16:38:31]  preprocess started ...
[16:38:31]  preprocess finished in 1 ms
[16:38:31]  webpack started ...
[16:38:31]  copy finished in 9.95 s
[16:38:39]  webpack finished in 8.16 s
[16:38:39]  sass started ...
[16:38:42]  sass finished in 2.86 s
[16:38:42]  postprocess started ...
[16:38:42]  postprocess finished in 17 ms
[16:38:42]  lint started ...
[16:38:42]  build dev finished in 21.01 s
[16:38:48]  lint finished in 6.12 s
> cordova build android

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2
(node:2404) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
    at D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\lib\check_reqs.js:370:19
    at _fulfilled (D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:854:54)
    at D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:883:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:13)
    at D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
(node:2404) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2404) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio>
```

Após instalada e setada nas variáveis de ambiente para jdk 1.8 segue o novo erro após recompilar e rodar o android com a versão 1.8:

```
D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio>ionic cordova build android
> ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform android
[10:38:27]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.0
[10:38:27]  build dev started ...
[10:38:27]  clean started ...
[10:38:27]  clean finished in 8 ms
[10:38:27]  copy started ...
[10:38:27]  deeplinks started ...
[10:38:27]  deeplinks finished in 59 ms
[10:38:27]  transpile started ...
[10:38:38]  transpile finished in 10.32 s
[10:38:38]  preprocess started ...
[10:38:38]  preprocess finished in 1 ms
[10:38:38]  webpack started ...
[10:38:38]  copy finished in 10.71 s
[10:38:46]  webpack finished in 8.50 s
[10:38:46]  sass started ...
[10:38:53]  sass finished in 6.52 s
[10:38:53]  postprocess started ...
[10:38:53]  postprocess finished in 14 ms
[10:38:53]  lint started ...
[10:38:53]  build dev finished in 25.75 s
[10:39:00]  lint finished in 7.26 s
> cordova build android
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
studio
(node:7508) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
    at Object.module.exports.check_gradle (D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\lib\check_reqs.js:150:18)
    at StudioBuilder.prepEnv (D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\StudioBuilder.js:216:23)
    at Api.module.exports.run (D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\lib\build.js:154:20)
    at D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js:342:43
    at _fulfilled (D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:854:54)
    at D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:883:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:13)
    at D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
(node:7508) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7508) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio>ionic cordova run android
> ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform android
[10:39:49]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.0
[10:39:49]  build dev started ...
[10:39:49]  clean started ...
[10:39:49]  clean finished in 11 ms
[10:39:49]  copy started ...
[10:39:49]  deeplinks started ...
[10:39:49]  deeplinks finished in 41 ms
[10:39:49]  transpile started ...
[10:39:59]  transpile finished in 9.60 s
[10:39:59]  preprocess started ...
[10:39:59]  preprocess finished in 1 ms
[10:39:59]  webpack started ...
[10:39:59]  copy finished in 10.03 s
[10:40:09]  webpack finished in 9.72 s
[10:40:09]  sass started ...
[10:40:12]  sass finished in 2.87 s
[10:40:12]  postprocess started ...
[10:40:12]  postprocess finished in 14 ms
[10:40:12]  lint started ...
[10:40:12]  build dev finished in 22.94 s
[10:40:18]  lint finished in 6.50 s
> cordova run android
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
studio
(node:284) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
    at Object.module.exports.check_gradle (D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\lib\check_reqs.js:150:18)
    at StudioBuilder.prepEnv (D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\StudioBuilder.js:216:23)
    at Api.module.exports.run (D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\lib\build.js:154:20)
    at D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js:342:43
    at _fulfilled (D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:854:54)
    at D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:883:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:13)
    at D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
(node:284) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:284) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio>
```

Nova tentativa, novo erro:

```
D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio>ionic cordova run android
> ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform android
[12:31:19]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.0
[12:31:19]  build dev started ...
[12:31:19]  clean started ...
[12:31:19]  clean finished in 297 ms
[12:31:19]  copy started ...
[12:31:21]  deeplinks started ...
[12:31:21]  deeplinks finished in 31 ms
[12:31:21]  transpile started ...
[12:31:54]  transpile finished in 32.65 s
[12:31:54]  preprocess started ...
[12:31:54]  preprocess finished in less than 1 ms
[12:31:54]  webpack started ...
[12:32:03]  copy finished in 44.14 s
[12:32:23]  webpack finished in 29.02 s
[12:32:23]  sass started ...
[12:32:39]  sass finished in 16.28 s
[12:32:39]  postprocess started ...
[12:32:39]  postprocess finished in 16 ms
[12:32:39]  lint started ...
[12:32:39]  build dev finished in 80.77 s
[12:32:48]  lint finished in 8.56 s
> cordova run android
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 26 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 26 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Platform 26].
  Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 31s
(node:6960) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Platform 26].
  Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 31s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:250:5)
(node:6960) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6960) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio>
```

Novo quadro completo:

```
D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio>ionic cordova run android
> ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform android
[19:10:32]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.0
[19:10:32]  build dev started ...
[19:10:32]  clean started ...
[19:10:33]  clean finished in 183 ms
[19:10:33]  copy started ...
[19:10:33]  deeplinks started ...
[19:10:33]  deeplinks finished in 47 ms
[19:10:33]  transpile started ...
[19:10:58]  transpile finished in 24.64 s
[19:10:58]  preprocess started ...
[19:10:58]  preprocess finished in 1 ms
[19:10:58]  webpack started ...
[19:11:02]  copy finished in 29.07 s
[19:11:16]  webpack finished in 18.66 s
[19:11:16]  sass started ...
[19:11:30]  sass finished in 13.86 s
[19:11:30]  postprocess started ...
[19:11:30]  postprocess finished in 90 ms
[19:11:30]  lint started ...
[19:11:31]  build dev finished in 58.16 s
[19:11:38]  lint finished in 7.94 s
> cordova run android
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_74uie4hd1mh3598jzv35vp9o9.run(D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\app\build.gradle:143)
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:platformAttrExtractor UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithStackFramesFixerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateSigningDebug
:app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:cdvBuildDebug UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2m 3s
46 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 45 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s):
        D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\Android\Radio\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
No target specified and no devices found, deploying to emulator
No emulator specified, defaulting to VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone
Waiting for emulator to start...
PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk]!
```

Comment: Eu diria só pelo que vc colocou que o que está errado no seu build seria o `JAVA_HOME`. É Importante baixar a versão especifica, ou seja, 1.8.0_65.

Comment: javac funciona normal.Então, JAVA_HOME está correta!

Comment: @Marconi  Só mais uma dúvida: De onde veio essa informação de que a versão do JAVA deve ser 1.8.0_65?

Comment: Eu desenvolvo um App Híbrido também, na documentação tinha uma versão do jdk específica, enquanto não instalei a versão específica não funcionou.

Comment: No tutorial que vc postou tem uma versão diferente da que vc tem instalado!

Comment: Entendi. Mas esse JDK é muito antigo. Será que no mais atual não tem o mais antigo por dentro?

Comment: Tem que ser o específico mesmo! No meu caso a versão 10 não servia, tive que usar a 8!

Comment: Entendo, mas a que está no tutorial não é a 8 mas sim 1.8.Mas vou instalar ela e setar nas variáveis de ambiente para ver se funciona!

Comment: Caro Carlos, como eu disse no outro comentário, 1.8 é o JDK 8. Aliais, tua JAVA_HOME aponta para o 1.8 e não para o a pasta do 10, logo pela lógica seria só editar o JAVA_HOME, não é verdade?

Comment: Bom, novo erro PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk]!. Na verdade, deu erro de falta de AVD  então vendo em um tutorial que o endereço seria o mesmo do android sdk, então apenas setei o mesmo endereço e deu esse novo erro. Mas o app-debug.apk foi gerado

Comment: @Guilherme, eu já havia setado para a versão 1.8. Tanto é verdade que está compilando normalmente. Agora só falta abrir o simulador. Mas falta corrigir o erro do comentário acima e setar corretamente a variável ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

Comment: Novo quadro completo no final da pergunta: Quaseeeeeeee deu certo! Quase...